# Input within an li with display block doesn't look good, why?

Tags: html, css

When I put an `input` with `type=text` within a `li` item with `display:block` I get weird results?
Here is an example:

```html
<ul>
  <li><input type="text" value="withvalue" style="display: block" /></li>
  <li><input type="text" style="display: block" /></li>
</ul>
```

For the first `input` I can only see the bullet when the `input` is focused and it's inside the `input`.
For the second `input`, it is not in the same line as the `li` parent bullet.

Can someone please explain it and maybe suggest a fix?

Thanks

Comment: why do you want to place the input boxes inside list item? lists are best suited for data, not controls.

Comment: I don't know why he chose that, but there are good reasons for doing so, like for example: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
<li style = "display:inline;"> ... </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

try without style="display: block"

```
<ul>
    <li><input type="text" value="withvalue" /></li>
    <li><input type="text" /></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
   
 ul{
   display:inline;
   line-style-type:none;
 }

 ul label{
   float:left;
   width:300px;
   margin-right:10px;
   text-align:right
}

</style>


<ul>
    <li><label>"your label"</label><input type="text"></li> 
    <li><label>"your label"</label><input type="text"></li>
    <li><label>"your label"</label><input type="text"></li>
</ul
```

Comment: You should add explanation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).